# Update resources in iOS app while it's running

Tags: ios, xcode

Does anyone know any way to update the resources (images, text files, UI .nib files etc) of an app, while it's running (e.g. while debugging in Xcode)?

Our app framework is becoming increasingly data-driven since we've released our first app. So it would be nice if I could simply press a button that checked for touched assets, and copied them across into the app's sandbox, *while the app is running*.

Then, I could simply press the back button, and re-open the part of the app that I'm testing, rather than do a full build cycle in Xcode.

It seems to me that there are 3rd party tools that are able to access iOS filesystems (e.g. iExplorer) so the know-how is out there? I guess it would have to be fairly intelligent and integrate with Xcode's resource copying build rules for the build target...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to update resources using Xcode is to rebuild and load the program onto the device or the simulator. If you want to get files from anywhere else into your app, you would have to write some code in your app to download files from the net. Plus, nib files have to be  recompiled with your code if you make changes; that's just the downside of using a compiled language I guess.

Comment: Ah, that's true, hadn't thought about the fact that nib files have to be compiled. Interesting idea that the assets could be pulled over a network rather than pushed direct to the device...

Comment: Yes, if you have frequent changing images or other files in your app, you can put them on your server and get them like this: `NSData *receivedData = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/example.png"]] retain];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:receivedData];` This would save you from doing app updates every time something changes.

Comment: Did I give you enough of an answer to mark it correct? Let me know if I can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can load nib files into your app after it's been compiled and installed.

http://www.indelible.org/ink/nib-loading/

Comment: The key part of the question is that the person is looking to do this while the app is running, how does your answer address that?